# jQuery, CSS3 or HTML5 transition?

Tags: jquery, html, css

What kind of transition (if it's a transition) does this web site when you click the main menu links?

http://ivalladare7.wix.com/testepi#!home/mainPage

It's just a test but I think the idea is clear. Is it HTML5, CSS or jQuery/JavaScript?

I saw it in a couple of places but I don't know how to implement it because I don't know how to find an example.

Any help appreciated

Comment: It's on the internet, you can look at the source.

Comment: CSS3 and the new javascript apis are part of HTML5, they are not separate. I don't think you understand what HTML5 is exactly, I would recommend you to read this intro http://www.html5rocks.com/en/why

Comment: @BBog You're right. I'll take a look at your link. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcomed! I'm a HTML5 newbie myself and I had the same misconception

Comment: @BBog There have been complaints on why W3C is lumping HTML5 with CSS3, SVG, and new JavaScript API when factualy those are diffrent, check this out http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-is-dead-long-live-html/

Comment: Interesting article but this is debatable if you ask me because HTML5 is not simply a HTML version number. However, this question is not an appropriate place for such a debate so...

Answer (score 1):

It's a CSS transition (and not a very good one as it's webkit only). A better version with vendor prefixes would be:

```
.menu a {
    color: #999;
            transition: color 0.4s ease; /* vendorless fallback */
         -o-transition: color 0.4s ease; /* opera */
        -ms-transition: color 0.4s ease; /* IE 10 */
       -moz-transition: color 0.4s ease; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transition: color 0.4s ease; /*safari and chrome */
}

.menu a:hover {
    color: #340065;
}
```

If you mean the sliding content, then that's Javascript.

Comment: Actually hold on, do you mean the content dropping in OR the colour fading?

Answer (score 1):

The HTML structure looks a bit daunting at a glance. I'm not sure which transition(?) do you mean, but I presume it is the sliding content when we click the menu.

At first I suspect it is some sort of Javascript (jQuery most likely), since it adds trails to the site URL in the address bar. Then I try to view the source (using Chrome's inspect element) and found there is no `<a>` element on the menu. I only found this:

```
<p skinpart="label" class="wysiwyg_viewer_skins_dropmenubutton_TextOnlyMenuButtonNSkinddm1-label" style="line-height: 25px; width: auto; ">Articles&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;Videos</p>
```

Then to make sure of it, I disable Javascript on the browser. The sliding content stops working. So, yeah, it is Javascript.

**EDIT:**

Actually if you try to view source (Ctrl+U) directly, you'll find a bunch of Javascript lines. And if you try to Ctrl+F the text `Home`, you'll find it within the lines of Javascript.  So this is indeed a JS.

Comment: Yes, I mean the sliding content. Sorry if I wasn't clear. I agree it's javascript but what. I don't want the exactly same solution just and example of how to slide the content. I think it's a really cool effect.

Comment: I think this is from a site builder (Wix) that used to make Flash sites. The code is insane.

Comment: Definitely a site builder when the code is as daunting as that... by the way, @nachovall, this is not exactly the same but I suppose it's a bit similar: http://www.queness.com/resources/html/scroll/vertical.html The tutorial is located here: http://www.queness.com/post/356/create-a-vertical-horizontal-and-diagonal-sliding-content-website-with-jquery

Comment: @deathlock this is exactly what I need. I also found this http://css.dzone.com/articles/html-page-slide-without I'll check both and I'll see the best option. Then I'll post the answer here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a CSS transition.

If you see the rule:

```
.wysiwyg_viewer_skins_dropmenubutton_TextOnlyMenuButtonNSkinddm1 {
-webkit-transition: color 0.4s ease 0s;
}
```

But you can get something better at: http://css3generator.com/

Choose transitions and use that tool. It will help you to get something more cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

Easy transitions on this website are made with css3 transitions.
However the sliding from the content transitions are made with TweenMax (Greensock)

It's a light weight script which can work perfectly with jQuery or vanilla js specially for tweening/animating.

Checkout their demo (animated with Greensock)

https://greensock.com/jump-start-js